# How do you add categories to the colors tab in calendar preferences

Tags: lotus-notes

Using lotus notes 8.5 I want to have different colors for different Categories. 
Now you can add categories easy enough but when you go to the Colors tab those new categories do not show up.  Therefore, I cannot change the color.

[image: Cats added]

Categories not showing up.

[image: Missing cats]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available in 8.5. coloring categories was introduced to Lotus Notes with Version 9. before that you could only color different types of appointment as your screenshot shows. 
Of course one could code the coloring for categories, but therefor you need a Designer Client and deep knowledege about coding Lotus Notes Databases...

So the only solution for you is to update your client and mail template to Version 9